# Search in an array of objects and return a value from the last corresponding Object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm struggling to return a value for last event containing "SearchResults" in the case below:
[schema of my datalayer where I want to collect the information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg6yG.png)

At the moment I achieved to write to following code in order to know if a SearchResult event exists or not:

```
    //Check if an existing event contains Search Results
if (digitalData.event.filter(e => e.componentID === 'SearchResults').length > 0) {    
    // If there are any that exist, I want to take the last one that was generated and return the pageIndex value of that one
    console.log("exist");  
    } else {
        // If it doesn't exist return 1
        return 1;
  };
```

Now I'm struggling to find a way to select only the last event generated and return the value contained in "digitalData.event.attributes.pageIndex".

Does anyone have any solution regarding this point ?

Thank you,

Comment: `searchResults.at(-1)` - it will return the last element of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just save that in a variable temporarily and return the last result. Is this what you wanted?

```
const searchResults = digitalData.event.filter(e => e.componentID === 'SearchResults')
if (searchResults.length > 0) {    
    const yourAnswer = searchResults[searchResults.length -1]
    console.log("exist");  
    } else {
        
        return 1;
  };
```

Comment: Hello ! So here what's in the const yourAnswer is the entire object that match the filter right ? How can I return a specific value from this now ?

Comment: Nevermind, I achieved to test it and make it work thanks to your solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Filter the items first, and if there are any take the last item:

```
const searchResults = digitalData.event.filter(e => e.componentID === 'SearchResults');
if (searchResults.length > 0) {
  // If there are any that exist, I want to take the last one that was generated and return the pageIndex value of that one
  return searchResults[searchResults.length-1].pageLength;
} else {
  // If it doesn't exist return 1
  return 1;
};
```

Comment: Hello, hmm apparently it's working only when the event doesn't exist otherwise, it's returning undefined.. Thank you for your advice anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Hello bro you can do what you want in this way.

```
let getResult = digitalData.event.filter(e => e.componentID === 'SearchResults' && e.componentID.length > 0 )
  
    if (getResult.length > 0) {
    const getIt = getResult[getResult.length - 1];
    getResult = getIt
    } 

    console.log(getResult)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it worked too !